# Why does the random seed impact on my back-propagation algorithm?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

after a whole class about Machine Learning I realize I don't have the slightest idea of how to build a NN even though I passed the exam. Therefore I tried to write one from scratch following the advice of this videohttps://youtu.be/I74ymkoNTnw?t=425

In order to test the NN code I tried to overfit over the first point and, for some reason, I get the exactly opposite result (output=(0, 1); expected=(1, 0) ) where the output are probability.

I tried to change the sign of the correction in the back propagation but I still get an error of 45% even after thousands iteration. Therefore I assumed the sign was correct and the problem lies elsewhere.

I'm working with Google Collab so you can check and run the whole code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j-WMk80t8mbg7vr5HscbTUJxUFxOK1yN

The function I'm assuming it's not working is the following:

```py
def back_propagation(self, x:np.ndarray, y:np.ndarray, y_exp:np.ndarray):
    error = 0.5*np.sum( (y-y_exp)**2 )

    Ep = y-y_exp  # d(Error) / d(y)
    dfrac = np.flip( self.out)/np.sum( self.out)**2 # d( x/sum(x) )/d(x)
    dsigm = self.out*(1-self.out) # d( 1/(1+exp(-x)) )/d(x) | out = sig(x)
    correction = np.outer(Ep*dfrac*dsigm, x) # Correction matrix

    self.NN *= 1-self.lr*correction
    return error
```

Where y was obtained through:

```
def forward_propagation(self, x:np.ndarray):
    Ax = self.NN.dot(x)
    self.out = self.sigmoid(Ax)
    y = self.out / np.sum( self.out)
    return y
```

Can someone lend me an hand?

PS: I haven't written english in a long time, if there is any error / unreadable part tell me, I'll try to explain myself better.

EDIT: I examined more the error then I have the + sign in the back-propagation and I noticed that changing the seed change the minimum error after 10002 iteration:

```
seed = 1000  --> error = 0.4443457394544875
seed = 1234  --> error = 3.484945305904348e-05
seed = 1     --> error = 2.8741028650796533e-05
seed = 10000 --> error = 0.44434995711021025
seed = 12345 --> error = 3.430037390869015e-05
seed = 100   --> error = 2.851979370926932e-05
```

Therefore I change the question from "Why is my back-propagation algorithm maximizing error?" to "Why does the random seed impact on my back-propagation algorithm?"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my code. There was a couple of errors:

1. As I'm doing gradient descent a minus sign was needed. (i got lost in math)
2. The correction is independent of the weight. Therefore the right way to do it is

   self.NN = self.NN - self.lr*correction

and not

```
self.NN *= 1-self.lr*correction
```

The fact that the seed changed my result was probably due to a low learning rate (when i wrote the question it was 0.1-0.5) it may be due to a local maximum (local maximum because I was wrongly trying to maximize error)

Hope my answer help someone else with a simular problem.